# py2neo: ImportError: cannot import name 'Rev'

Tags: python-3.x, neo4j, py2neo

I have 4.2 version of py2neo
[  py2neo in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (4.2.0) ]

and when importing in my python script, seeing this error

```
from py2neo import Graph, Node, Path, Rev
ImportError: cannot import name 'Rev'
```

also when using Path

```
path_1 = Path(bradley,"Knows",matthew, "Knows", lisa)
graph.create(path_1)
path_3 = path_1.append("Knows",path_2)
AttributeError: 'Path' object has no attribute 'append'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using old code in a new version of py2neo. The `Rev` class was removed a while ago (you just need a regular `Relationship` now) and you can concatenate paths now with the addition operator:
https://py2neo.org/v4/data.html#path-objects-and-other-walkable-types